# Azure AD SAML entity ID allowed characters

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, rightnow-crm

I am trying to implement SSO in Oracle Service cloud (RightNow CRM) using Azure AD SAML. The entity ID of Oracle Service cloud is alphanumeric and has couple of special characters (Ex: RNT-SP-1-*{alphanumeric}*=). But Azure AD SAML configuration accepts only Urls. Is there a way to put entity ID with special characters in Azure SAML configuration

Comment: Oracle Service Cloud will have a metadata document for SAML integration with IDP(i.e Azure AD). Try to get those details from Oracle Vendor.

Comment: Prashanth - I exported the metadata document and the entity ID within the document is in _RNT-SP-1-{alphanumeric}=_  format. The Azure AD is not allowing to put '=' character

Comment: Raise a support request with Azure engineer

Comment: I have raised a support ticket with Microsoft Support. Support has confirmed that there is some issue at the backend when Entity ID with special character at the end is saved, they are involving Product team to rectify.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure, you must use a URI as "entity ID" for the SAML configuration.

Shouldn't the entiry ID of Oracle Service cloud be in the same URI format? https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/middleware/oracle-identity-cloud-service.html

Comment: Yes, Oracle updated the Entity ID to url based on our request. But in Azure, there is no restriction that Entity ID must be URL. It cannot accept when "=" character is at the end of Entity ID. Microsoft Support is looking at the issue